# Error with strlen($string) > 20

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am not experienced using PHP and installed a script (which went well). I then made a few adjustments using the main setting menu.

When I use the script now, I get the following error (displayed prominently on almost every page):

> Error:
>   Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/castillo/public_html/membership/inc/libs/plugins/modifier.myescape.php on line 28

Site is: http://castilloflamingo.com/membership/

When I go to the file: modifier.myescape.php
I see this on line 28:

```
if (strlen($string) > 20)
```

How can I fix it? Can someone offer some ideas?

Comment: Please show var_dump($string);

Comment: A string is a text. An array is an indexed collection of assorted items. You can say that "cat" has three letters, buy you normally can't count the letters of a zoo.

Comment: I did a quick Google search on your particular issue, and noticed many [similar issues](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/208995-many-errors-in-website/#post_id_1091729). Would it be easier for you to use an alternative script?

Comment: A string is a text. An array is an indexed collection of assorted items. You can say that "cat" has three letters, buy you normally can't count the letters of a zoo. –  Álvaro G. Vicario 

Nice really nice, but what can I do about it to make it work?

TIA

Comment: To get different script? Well, maybe if I have to, but I love the functions and simplicity of this one.
I did find some explication in following your link, but again - I have no idea what are they talking about.

#3 - The "strlen function expects ..." indicates that one of the parameters passed to that function are not the expected type (it tells you which one). This indicates that $string is not a string (might be an array, or object, or null, or something).

I did managed to check the: modifier.myescape.php on line 28 but have no idea if I should change something or how....

TIA

Comment: @Ivonne - Well, to make it work you need to look at the code; not just that line, the surrounding code as well. I just gave you an insight on what the error means. If you are not comfortable with code, you should probably consider switching to a ready-to-use alternative. This is a programming site and we can't give you other adivce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd need more info to say for sure, but give this a try:

```
if (strlen($string[0]) > 20)
```

The error message indicates the $string variable is an array, so check the code where $string is being generated and see if you can make any sense of why/how it is an array.

Comment: 1 Show us your code ! –  ôkio 2 hours ago

I am a total nobe so I don't understand the question. What code, where ?

TIA

Comment: I am a total nobe so I don't understand the instruction Deigo , so bare with me..... 
Please show var_dump($string)
Where is it or what?

TIA

Comment: Mister, master, guru, God mw_goodjava you are THE man. You fixed it. I am exited and very happy - the site works nice......

THANK YOU VERY MUCH *****

Comment: I would like to ask 2 more simple questions:

Comment: mw_goodjava - can I give you Good points or reputation? If yes HOW?